Why install a flow resister in a combo filter and 6" rain shower head?
I have just installed a combination 20 cycle filter and a 6 inch rain shower head in my shower. The pressure is quite high. I am in a 3rd floor condo and would not want to damage the pipes and cause problems for people living below. Should I instal a flow resister to avoid any problems?
I am a 76 year old woman with little to no knowledge of basic plumbing. Thanks for this!
